# unziped and ziped again XPS file is treated by viewer as invalid

Tags: xps, xpsdocument

Steps which I made are the following:

1. Create .doc file , filled with some content.
2. Print .doc to .xps
3. unzip .xps via 7zip
   "DID NOT CHANGE ANYTHING"
4. zip again via 7zip
5. during opening via XPS Viewer EP (XpsRchVw.exe) rise error "...The document may not be a valid XPS document"

any clue what's the reason ?

Comment: Whatever freaky zip implementation 7zip is using isn't recognized by the viewer.  Use a different zip program.

Comment: ehh I was zipping back entire folder instead of it's content so that's what caused problems.